# UICollectionViewCell does not fit device screen

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uicollectionview

I am trying to make the UICollectionViewCell fit the screen width.

In the interface builder, it looks like this:

[image]

When I build and run on iPhone 6, it looks like this:

[image]
(As you can see, I want to fill the width on left and right side.

I tried adding this in the `cellForItemAtIndexPath`:

```
cell.frame.size = CGSizeMake(UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width, cell.bounds.size.height)
```

But this made the cell move to the right side, so a part of the cell it out of the screen view..

My `cellForItemAtIndexPath` looks like this:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
    {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell  

        cell.frame.size = CGSizeMake(UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width, cell.bounds.size.height)

        cell.flagContentButton.titleLabel?.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
        cell.uploadedTimeLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
        cell.imageText.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true

        cell.layer.borderWidth = 0.5
        cell.layer.cornerRadius = 3
        let myColor : UIColor = UIColor(red: 0.0, green: 0.0, blue:0.0, alpha: 0.15)
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        cell.layer.borderColor = myColor.CGColor

        if (self.arrayOfDetails.count > indexPath.row){
            let post = self.arrayOfDetails[indexPath.row]
            cell.imageText.text = post.text
            cell.objectID.append(post.objID)
            cell.uploadedTimeLabel.text = post.CreatedAt.timeAgo

            cell.imageView.setImageWithUrl(NSURL(string: post.image)!, placeHolderImage: UIImage(named: "Placeholder"))
        }

        return cell
    }
```

**EDIT**:

I tried adding this code:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
        // Code below
        return CGSizeMake(UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width, 126)
    }
```

That made the width fit good, but the image and text did not move:
[Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zqe5L.png)

Comment: Have you checked the content insets for your collection view?

Comment: @pbush25 - Yes, it´s all 0.

Comment: Did you use auto layout?

Comment: @SuttikeatWitchayakul No, i don´t use auto layout: http://s8.postimg.org/epcjy7y91/Screen_Shot_2015_11_18_at_13_09_02.png

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're a victim of `UIEdgeInsets` defaulting to not zero on iOS 8+. You can set these in Interface Builder:

[image]

Or in code:

**UITableView:**

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if ([cell respondsToSelector:@selector(setSeparatorInset:)]) {
        [cell setSeparatorInset:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
    }

    if ([cell respondsToSelector:@selector(setPreservesSuperviewLayoutMargins:)]) {
        [cell setPreservesSuperviewLayoutMargins:NO];
    }

    if ([cell respondsToSelector:@selector(setLayoutMargins:)]) {
        [cell setLayoutMargins:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
    }
}
```

**UICollectionView:**

Add the delegate `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` to your view controller interface, then:

```
- (UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout insetForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section
{
    return UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: Where in the interface builder? And the line `cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero` did not work in Swift.

Comment: This is mine: http://s30.postimg.org/kmj4zqh9d/Screen_Shot_2015_11_18_at_01_13_34.png

Comment: You configure this right on the table/collection view itself. Select the table/collection view in IB, then on the right pane, you'll see the layout margins. If you're using AutoLayout, you might also need to adjust the constraints to not use margins.

Comment: I am not using table view. I am using CollectionView
- I have disabled Auto Layout.

Comment: Sorry, same thing though if you're using IB. Slightly different in code - see update.

Comment: Could you please check my **EDIT** in my answer, and see if you understand the current problem? :)

Comment: Can you post an image of your positioning in interface builder for the image? For what it's worth, this is why using AutoLayout is a good thing ;)

Comment: @brandonscript I am using AutoLayout, still having this issue.